# How to get for each value in one array column number in another array?

Tags: google-sheets, match, array-formulas, appearance, excel-indirect

Please look the [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EASXorbiiZO7yd4l0BEoO9XkKi6vKY86Da0_vIjGlN4/edit?usp=sharing). The 'sheet1' is a gradually filled table. In column "A" some kind of ID for each entity. These identifiers are sometimes repeated. In the result I just want to know the appearance number of each ID.

To solve this I created 'sheet2'. in 'sheet2' column 'A' list of unique values from 'sheet1'. Then with huge formula in cell 'sheet2!B2' I get all row numbers for each unique value from 'sheet1' separated by columns. And finally I want to get in 'sheet1' column numbers for each rownumber from 'sheet2'.

I want to use 'match' comand, but it perfectly works without 'arrayformula' like you can see in 'sheet1' column E.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2);;MATCH(B2;INDIRECT("'sheet2'!B"&C2&":Z"&C2)))
```

And i don't understand whats going wrong in 'sheet1' column D, when I try to add 'arayformula'

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A);;MATCH(B2:B;INDIRECT("'sheet2'!B"&C2:C&":Z"&C2:C))))
```

I read many posts about these commands doesn't work together like I want. there must be some another way. But my imagination is over. Please help.

**Expected result:**

```
value 1 |   1   |(first appearance of 'value 1')

value 2 |   1   |(first appearance of 'value 2')

value 1 |   2   |(second appearance of 'value 1')

value 3 |   1   |(first appearance of 'value 3')

value 4 |   1   |(first appearance of 'value 4')

value 5 |   1   |(first appearance of 'value 5')

value 3 |   2   |(second appearance of 'value 3')

value 3 |   3   |(third appearance of 'value 3')

value 4 |   2   |(second appearance of 'value 4')

value 5 |   2   |(second appearance of 'value 5')
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed...

Answer (score 0):

In G2 I entered this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(A2:A);SORT(ROW(A2:A);A2:A;1);1)-MATCH(A2:A;SORT(A2:A);0)-ROW()+2))
```

See if that works for you?

[image: Explanation:]

Comment: It looks so simple. I am ashamed, i don't understand how does this formula work)) i'll go to figure it out. maybe you can say few words about logic?)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I look at this sheet every day but I absolutely can not understand what is happening in step 2. Can you explain, please?

Comment: Hi @OlegBlonskiy, Sorry for the time it took to reply, but I was away. Basically, think of step 2 as a lookup of row numbers. I added some more clarification to the spreadsheet. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(Z2:Z="";"";COUNTIFS(Z2:Z;Z2:Z;ROW(Z2:Z);"<="&ROW(Z2:Z))))
```

The result >

## Ref

1   A
2   A
1   B
1   C
3   A