# How to get the the sequential number on duplicates?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not sure how to word this correctly, but I need to get the sequential number on duplicates in google sheets. For example, column `Count` is what I'm looking for:

```
+-------+-------+
| Name  | Count |
+-------+-------+
| Joe   |     1 |
| Lisa  |     1 |
| Jenny |     1 |
| Lisa  |     2 |
| Lisa  |     3 |
| Joe   |     2 |
| Jenny |     2 |
```

Sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BB4bzzR3TTAfW5SwvNG_W3AsIYqlSEaSOad5wB4sdko/edit#gid=0

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For an array-enabled solution, you could try in C1

```
={"Count"; ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(A2:A),SORT(ROW(A2:A),A2:A,1),1)-MATCH(A2:A,SORT(A2:A),0)-ROW()+1))}
```

For more background, also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55952426/how-to-get-for-each-value-in-one-array-column-number-in-another-array/55953253?noredirect=1#comment98818092_55953253).

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it's: `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)`